# Check if user exists (and go on...)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a message system where users can send messages to eachother. But now I want to check if a username exists when sending the message. I'm developing this on symfony 2.

I went to the IRC channel of them and they told me to use the UniqueConstraint of Doctrine, but it does exactly the opposite of what I want it to do. I want to check if a username exists, if yes the user can send it.

So is there any way to "turnaround" the behaviour ?

Comment: Just use the UniqueConstraint. If the Insert fails, check the error message. If its from the constrained field, you know the user doesnt exist. This is much saner than doing a query first to see if the username exists and then maybe doing the insert imo.

Comment: Well the uniqueConstraint does a query too to your database so it doesn't really matter ?

Comment: yes, it it does only *one* query instead of the potential *two* when the username exists and the message can be inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check if a username exists, if yes ...

You `SELECT` your username, for example through `createQuery` and the proper DQL statement ... and if the result set holds at least one user, then a user with this username exists.